# Is there a way to control the font size of MathJax equations?

Tags: support, feature-request

Some equations have nested fractions and radicals e.g.:

[image]

([which is the relationship of temperature between a planet and a star based on a radiative energy balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation#Temperature_relation_between_a_planet_and_its_star))

Mathjax renders the equation this size:

[image]

which makes it hard to read some variables. I am wondering: is any way to increase the size of the font?

Comment: looks like using "\cfrac" instead of "\frac" will help quite a bit with this specific example; still curious if there's font size control though

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems MathJax supports [size Latex commands](http://www.forkosh.com/latex/ltx-178.html):

- `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\small`, `\normalsize` (default), `\large`, `\Large` (capital "L"), `\LARGE` (all caps), `\huge`, `\Huge` (capital "H")

Which go from smallest to largest. A quick test showed that `\large` or `\Large` worked rather well for the equation you have above (getting larger might be just too much).

However, a temporary fix (for you only) is as follows:

1. Right click on any MathJax equations in any post
2. Select `Math Settings`
3. Select the last option, `Scale all math...`
4. Enter any number you want in the pop-up

Note that this applies site-wide (I believe that it edits your JavaScript file) but, again,  for you only.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!